# Difference between using kv file and python class for initializing a widget

Tags: python, kivy

I was learning how to create an App with Kivy and I see that the App looks different when I use Python vs kv language.

What I am trying to do is to get the background colored red. 
When I do it with Python, I get a little red box at the bottom left corner (probably, the default 100px kivy widget size).
When I do it with the kv file, I get the entire background colored red

Here is my python code -

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import *

class MyWidget(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        with self.canvas:
            Color(1,0,0,1)
            Rectangle(size = self.size, pos = self.pos)


class MyWidgetApp(App):
    def build(self):
        x = MyWidget()
        return x
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyWidgetApp().run()
```

Here is my kv file

```
<MyWidget@Widget>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 0, 0, 1.0
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
```

Why does this happen? And how can I set the background color from Python?
I am using Python 2.7 on a Linux machine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that kv automatically makes a binding to update the red rectangle position and size, while python doesn't (and can't). You have to use the `bind` method to create your own binding. I have a blog post about this [here](http://inclem.net/2014/10/10/kivy/kivy_update_instructions/) - coincidentally, it addresses precisely your example.